# Alternative to providing individuals references during job application

Tags: job-search, references

I am currently jobless and looking for a job. I am sending applications to those job ads I deem fit me. I have been 13 years in the industry now, i.e. since I graduated.

I sent my application to a start-up whose activities, etc appealed to me and they texted me to have an interview the next day. Note that the position is not a management role, is not an executive role.

So I did that initial interview and after that initial interview we had a salary discussion, made sure we both are on the same page. After that, they invited me to two more technical interviews to evaluate my technical skills on the field of the position. So I had in total three interviews. After that third interview, they contacted me the next day and invited me for one more interview. In the email inviting me for another interview, they added this:

> Provide Reference Checks
> Please provide us with the contact information for three reference checks, including their phone number, positions, names, as well as a brief description of how you are related to each reference.
> These reference checks are an important aspect if our decision-making process, and gathering this information in advance will help us in making a timely final offer, should you successfully pass the final interview.

I promptly contacted them and asked if they prefer a reference who was above me, like a C-level or they prefer a peer. To my surprise, they answered they actually want THREE references, one below (that I mentored), one peer, and one above.

So, my problem is, I feel super uncomfortable with this thing of the references. I already feel super violent and uncomfortable providing one reference, so providing 3 references makes me terribly uncomfortable.

The reasons why this makes me so uncomfortable is that I am a person very concerned with my privacy, and providing these three references means I have to go back to people of my past and let them know all the details of what companies I am applying to, what the company do, why I apply for it, why I need them to help me, asking if they are ok to be contacted, etc. I am not a super extroverted person, and not a super social person. So I feel really violent and uncomfortable doing this. But of course, I want this job and I do not want them to think that I do not want to provide a reference because I screwed up something in my past jobs - which I did not, those references would be totally legit and available.

So while I COULD provide those references, I feel uncomfortable providing them and I have, per my personal judgement - I do not expect anyone to share this, is my personal judgement - an over exigence and over asking three references, and even one, for the kind of role that I apply for that is not executive, not management, does not deal directly with customers, children, elderly people, or anyone except colleges.

So, after all this context, my question is, is there any alternative I can suggest, instead of the references? Or otherwise, how can I justify to them that I do not want to provide a reference? I thought to tell them upfront I feel very violent because this forces me to share my private life, i.e. what companies I apply to is no-one's concern, in my privacy's view . But also I would like to come up with an equivalent solution. I thought of asking them if it is enough if I get a reference in my LinkedIn profile instead, or something like this.

Comment: Whatever you do, don't say "violent" or "violet", that's the wrong word. Even the word "violated" seems a little too strong. Anyway, could you obtain two references at least? In any case, I think you should try to get references. It's not as bad as you think. People usually want to help. It's possible that they'll need a reference themselves some day.

Comment: The real alternative is to apply for a job elsewhere. In my personal experience, 99% of the jobs don't require references at all. -- The best and most authentic references you can have is to do perfectly well during the interviews to prove that you deserve the jobs.

Comment: @Job_September_2020 - well, if a security clearance is involved, getting the three professional references is the least of their concerns. Given details in the question that seems unlikely though...

Comment: Providing 3 references has been completely standard for my entire working life, some 45 years now. I always call references as a hiring manager. They have always been happy to talk about the candidate.

Comment: Thank you so much guys. I really read all the comments and each of them made sense to me. I really appreciate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can ask about alternatives, but the more you resist the process, the more suspicious they'll become.

I understand your situation, but I think the best way out is through. Try to find out three contacts, and share the same. Chances are, they might not even call them, but if you resist or try to talk about alternatives, they'll make sure that they call them. It is the way it is, so in my opinion, best way is to simply comply.

That said,

> *I have to go back to people of my past and let them know all the details of what companies I am applying to, what the company do, why I apply for it, why I need them to help me, asking if they are ok to be contacted, etc.*

Well, you only need to mention the first and the last point, for most of the people that should suffice. You need not be a *best buddy* to them, usually most of the people you work with will be happy to spend couple of minutes to respond to a call to let the caller know you were a good person to work with (unless you were really, really a pain in the rear for them while you worked with them).

Comment: Makes a lot of sense. Yes I could provide the three ideal candidates, and ask them that if they want to contact them, please let me know in advance so that I can prevent them. That way, maybe they eventually decide not to contact them. But yes I feel super violent with it and I agree with you, the more I look like I am uncomfortable, the more they'll suspect something fishy. BUT what happens with me? i.e. I have boundaries, I cannot do just any and everything I am asked to during an interview. Yet I am interested in the job.

Comment: @Worker I understand that you feel tense about it, but perhaps overreacting? If you do it, you will forget about it later anyway and feel better. Like, if you go to a doctor they might see you naked, the dentist experience is painful and scary, yes. Some people faint when they get an injection or blood drawn. But avoiding medical care for 60 years won't work. So hold your nose and jump. It is very unlikely to cause you any problems. You would not believe the detailed security check going back over 10 years I had to go through.

Comment: "violent" is absolutely the wrong word. I think you mean "violated", and either way it's a completely unjustified and unrealistic response. You need to get used to the fact that people want reassurance that they can trust you before making a big bet on your being the right candidate. This is the way the world works. Get used to it, or you're just going to hurt yourself.

Answer (score 7):

> So while I COULD provide those references, I feel uncomfortable providing them and I have a, per my personal judgement - I do not expect anyone to share this, is my personal judgement - an over exigence and over asking three references, and even 1, for the kind of role that I apply for that is not executive, not management, does not deal directly with customers, children, elderly people, or anyone except colleges.

Then you should seek another employment because this is clearly a big enough cultural rift that makes you feel violated, which is quite a serious feelings and references like this are clearly embedded into the way they work.

Although I will add that asking and providing references is very common thing, and a pretty great way to weed out fakes in the applicant pool, even if you won't then contact any/all of them at all. The fact of needing them is usually enough. And as @Sourav explained in her answer, this doesn't require someone close, just some people you've worked with and may have perfectly had no contact since - that is bog standard and normal thing that happens all the time.

To address few other points.

> I thought to tell them upfront I feel very violent because this forces me to share my private life - i.e. what companies I apply to is none's concern, in my privacy's view

While you have the right to privacy, wanting this level of privacy and separation where your past only exists as the way you present it, and the two shall never meet, is going to raise a big yellow flag with many recruiters and a question of "why is he so afraid for us to learn anything about their past?".

And I don't think there's a good answer to that question, and if they start to suspect that you are hiding things your candidacy will get into trouble rather fast.

> I thought of asking them if it is enough if I get a reference in my LinkedIn profile instead, or something like this.

That is another, tightly controlled by you, one way street you are trying to present them and will likely only raise more questions as now you are happy to ask that person to provide a reference, with their name attached to it, but very clearly it's the bidirectional communications that you oppose to so strongly. As you can guess, that's likely to arise suspicion.

Answer (score 5):

> how can I justify to them that I do not want to provide a reference?

You can simply tell them that you are not comfortable providing any references. Be prepared with an answer when they ask why.

Maybe they don't really care. But almost certainly you'll be dropped from consideration. (When I was a hiring manager, I would never consider someone who refused to provide any references.)

It's your choice to decide if your comfort and desire for privacy is more important than the chance for this job.

If you do decide to remove yourself from consideration for this job, think about what you will do going forward. You may want to express to recruiters that you won't be providing any references. That way, you'll avoid wasting your time and their time as well.

I strongly recommend that you reconsider this stance. But in the end, it's your choice to make.

Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

**You're completely overthinking this.**

One thing I've done is that I avoid giving any references until the last stages of the interview process.  Since I've worked a lot with recruiters for contract work, this keeps them from bothering people.

Second, I avoid giving management references.  The wrong recruiter will turn a management reference over to others trying to get new business, and sour things.  The last thing I'd want a former manager to do is associate my name with people calling to try to pitch their product or service.

Third, I only give out references for people who I *already* know won't have a problem giving one for me.  So I don't have to call around saying, "hey, someone's going to call you for a reference," which in OP's case seems to be a huge source of anxiety.